# C# InvalidOperationException with backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, exception, backgroundworker, dispatcher

I have this line in my backgroundWorker thread:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.Network.Nodes.Add(node))).Wait();
```

I'm getting an exception InvalidOperationException from it.

Comment: I need to update a UI component, WPF MVVM, so i need to access the ui thread for update

Comment: I tried working with the report progress and that didn't go well..

Comment: Add the context and full error message. Right now it's not answerable.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that

```
BeginInvoke(...).Wait()
```

would deadlock if you are currently on the UI thread. Try using `Invoke` instead.

Comment: But how can i wait for the action to finish?

Comment: Invoke is synchronous, it will return when the action is finished. Just replace BeginInvoke with Invoke and remove the .Wait() at the end.